# Why is the one mind upgrade not showing up?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I checked many websites online and checked with my friends for all of the requirements to have the upgrade but it just won't show up! I reloaded already and waited for about 3 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Bingo Center Research Facility upgrades are time based, but not *time* based. They used frames, as well as being dependent on how many upgrades have been purchased previously. Make sure you’ve purchased all the upgrades before it, first. Then, wait. According to the wiki, with no heavenly upgrades or normal upgrades pertaining to research purchased, it should take 30 minutes at 30fps.